# set not to use vpn for specific urls (ip range)

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

How to config my PPTP VPN connection to being used for all traffic, except specific IP range (or urls)?

I'm a linux newbie with no network knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the "route" or "ip route" commands, they allow you to manipulate what path linux will use to reach specific networks.

I would guess that currently your PPTP device is being used as the "default gateway". You will want to add route via your normal network card to the IP range. If these IPs are not the local subnet then you will need to also include the local gateway.

This link should help: http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-route.html